# How to remove the extra newline in the output?

Tags: arrays, c, string

program for reverse string  :

```
/**
 * C program to reverse order of words in a string
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 100 // Maximum string size

int main()
{
    char str[100], reverse[100];
    int len, i, index, wordStart, wordEnd;

    printf("Enter any string: ");
    fgets(str,sizeof(str),stdin);

    len   = strlen(str);
    index = 0;

    // Start checking of words from the end of string
    wordStart = len - 1;
    wordEnd   = len - 1;

    while(wordStart > 0)
    {
        // If a word is found
        if(str[wordStart] == ' ')//means blank space
        {
            // Add the word to the reverse string
            i = wordStart + 1;
            while(i <= wordEnd)
            {
                reverse[index] = str[i];

                i++;
                index++;
            }
            reverse[index++] = ' ';

            wordEnd = wordStart - 1;
        }

        wordStart--;
    }

    // Finally add the last word
    for(i=0; i<=wordEnd; i++)
    {
        reverse[index] = str[i];
        index++;
    }

    // Add NULL character at the end of reverse string
    reverse[index] = '\0'; 

    printf("Original string:%s\n\n", str);
    printf("Reverse  string:%s", reverse);

    return 0;
}
```

and output:

```
Enter any string: stack overflow
Original string: stack overflow
Reverse  string: overflow
stack
```

my expected output:

```
Enter any string: stack overflow
Original string: stack overflow
Reverse  string: overflow stack
```

I am trying to reverse a string word by word but reverse string is not printed in same line.

Comment: Please start by picking *one* language. C and C++ are two very different languages, and the natural solution would be very different in them.

Comment: To solve whatever problems you have with your current code, this seems like a good time to learn how to [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your programs. For example by using a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to step through it line by line while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I think the error is hard to spot when you look at it, because it is an invisible character. But I agree that this could be easily debugged when you output the character codes or analyze them online or so.

Comment: Also note that your code doesn't handle trailing spaces at all, not only newlines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fgets` gets reads the input line, including the newline character caused by pressing Enter. So, if you enter `stack overflow`, the actual content of str becomes `stack overflow\n`.

```c
if (len > 0 && str[len - 1] == '\n') {
    str[len - 1] = '\0';
    len--;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this gets it.  I'm hoping everyone will notice that OP was asking for a solution to the newline issue in the output -- *not how to reverse a string*.   The title is a bit misleading.

Comment: True, the question title should be changed or the question deleted.

Comment: I submitted a title change edit.  It's in the approval queue.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could use:

```
str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = '\0';
```

to strip the newline from the string.

Answer (score 1):

Another (simple) alternative that gets the job done:

```
(void)strtok( str, "\n" ); // trim LF from end of string
```

Use `(void)` to demonstrate you know what you're doing...

(PS: Don't call `strlen()` until **AFTER** trimming the LF from the string's end...)